# Stuck on “Downloading… Do not turn off target!” when trying to boot via adb on Samsung Tab

Tags: adb, samsung, bootloader

I wish to flash a custom ROM on my Samsung Galaxy Tab A. To do this, I downloaded ADB and TWRP-3.2.3-0. when I run the command `adb reboot bootloader`, my tab gets stuck on `downloading... do not turn off target`.

I know how to get out of this screen (power + vol- + home), but how can I get past this screen so that I can flash TWRP?